# Check if text is in something - Discord Js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

developers! I'm making a Roblox Verification bot and I need to see if there is text located inside of a user's blurb.

I've tried a few things, the issue is, I don't want them to just set the blurb to the code, I'll explain.

If I do

```
if(emojis === blurb){
//do stuff
}
```

then it'll only work if the blurb is exactly the code.

I want it to trigger if the emojis are inside the blurb at all.

So if the emojis are  and their blurb is: "Bob ate an apple ", the code will trigger.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've fixed it!

The correct code is:

```
if(blurb.includes(emojiList)){
// do something
{
```